# XSockets with .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, websocket, xsockets.net

I've been trying to set up a new Smart Device Project (VS 2008) with XSockets.Client 4.0.0 for .NET 3.5, but after lots and lots of trials and errors, still no such luck.

The thing is, if I add all three package dependencies (XSockets.Client35, Newtonsoft.Json and System.Threading) I get the following error:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Func`2' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

...which I guess means that my System.Core Compact is missing something that the full .NET System.Core has (this is not really clear yet, I would be happy to get a better explanation).

And if I just set up the project with XSockets.Client35 I can deploy it, but the my application freezes when it starts (I've tested and I just have to reference the library for it to freeze).

So, my question is: is XSockets compatible with .NET Compact Framework? If not, is there a way to connect to any WebSocket server from a PocketPC (with Windows Mobile 6)?

Microsoft has some points regarding raw socket connections (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172494(v=vs.90).aspx), but does it apply to websockets also?

Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSockets.Client for .NET 3.5 is for .NET Framework 3.5 and not .NET Compact Framework 3.5.

I know of custom implementation that run Compact Framework clients to connect to XSockets, but there is currently no official client for .NET CF released by Team XSockets.

The current clients are

- JavaScript
- .NET 4.0+
- .NET 3.5
- .NET MicroFramework
- Dart
- Arduino

Since you can connect anything talking TCP/IP to XSockets it will be very easy to connect a client from Compact Framework as well.

There will be new a client for Java soon, but you can always contact the team if you have wishes for a Compact Framework client (or build it your self of course).

Regards
Uffe